# Built in mic distortion with ubuntu 13.10

Tags: alsa, microphone, soundcard

I Have a serous problem considering my Built in mic in my Lenovo laptop `ideapad S400`,  i get distortion sound every time i use my mic either was for hangout, skype or recording my screen, its like my mic is always boosted and there is a heavy noise in the background.

I could lower it a bit but i still get noise in the background, also my voice recording is very low.

I tried couple of solutions such as adding these lines to this file->`/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf`

```
options snd-hda-intel model=generic
options snd-usb-audio index=-2
options snd-hda-intel position_fix=3
```

Also tried to adjust my mic configuration via `alsamixer` via terminal.

My sound card is -> `HDA-Intel - HDA Intel PCH`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I upgraded the last package for my sound card and the problem some how solved, the distortion still there but i can raise up my mic to a level that the distortion is very low and does n't annoy the one i am calling.